# How to join multiple objects without overlapping?

Tags: objects

So, I made an object with multiple objects overlapping each other. Now I want to join everything in one unique object, without overlapping parts.

For example, this cool guy:

[image: Cool Guy]

If I active the wireframe view, we can see overlapping parts:

[image: Cool Guy Wireframe]

And what I want is this:

[image: Cool Guy Wanted]

I made this example using the Boolean Modifier with Union, but it doesn't work with more complex objects, like this one:

[image]

Where the cube is an object, and the cylinder another. Union just goes crazy, maybe for the overlap at top.

In resume, what I want is a way to take the shape of a group of objects, and apply it to a new object, avoiding internal overlappings.

Sorry for bad english, I hope you understands.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103322/boolean-union-with-overlapping-faces/ ?